# OpenAM Configured SAML Response Encryption

Tags: encryption, saml, openam

How do I configure OpenAM (with OpenDS behind it as the identity provider) to encrypt the SAML Response Assertion?

The messages are working fine, but I want to encrypt the Assertions with a certificate I have placed into the OpenAM keystore.jks.  I can't find anything in the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAML does not support ecryption of the whole Response and there shoudnt be any sensetive information in it besides in the assertion. The assertion or attributes is probably what you want to encrypt. Elements that can be encrypted are NameID, assertion attributes and whole assertions.

Encryption of the assertion or attributes can be set up in the Service provider configuration in OpenAM.

OpenAM Main Page -> Federation -> Entity Providers -> Click the service proved you want to give encrypted assertion -> Assertion Content -> Encryption -> check assertion

Comment: Edited my question.  Yes, it's the assertion I'm concerned about.

Comment: Thanks.  I still have a little to learn about getting the SP metadata and certificates all lined up, but at least I'm looking in the right places now.