# How can we change Openam encryption algorithm for assertion of SAML2?

Tags: encryption, saml, saml-2.0, openam

I know that we can encrypt the assertion, nameID and attribute in openam. Check following link to know how.

[OpenAM Configured SAML Response Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959420/openam-configured-saml-response-encryption)

But by default openam encrypts using AES-128.

```
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"/>
```

I want the encryption to be AES-256.

Is there a way to change encryption algorithm for SAML response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can modify Encryption Algorithm in

Configuration -> Global -> Security Token Service -> Signing and Encryption

after logging in as amadmin

verified on ForgeRock OpenAM 10.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the encryption algorithm in the Service Provider MetaData, see 'EncryptionMethodType' in SAML schema.

If nothing is configured encryption algorithm defaults to 'AES-128'